# My loop isnt decreasing the right way

Tags: javascript, loops, output

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    window.onload = start;

    function start() {
      var money = 1000 * 0.97
      for (var i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
        for (var x = 0; x <= 15; x++) {
          money--
        }
        document.getElementById("utskrift").innerHTML += i + " Years in the future your money is worth " + money + " Kr today." + "<br/>"
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="utskrift"></p>

  <body>

</html>
```

Okay so my output starts at 954 kr on 0 years. It should be 1000 and decrease by 3% (1000*0.97) every year for 15 years from there on. Im really close but i cant see the mistake?

Comment: `var money = 1000*0.97` ???

Comment: your code starts at 970, and you decrement money 16*16 times which is `254` for an end result of 714.  What you want to do is `i = 1; i <=15` which will run 15 times, and then `money =  money * 0.97` to decrease it by 3% each year for a result of `614.25` ish

Answer (score 2):

```
function start(){
  var money = 1000 *0.97
  for (var i = 0; i <15; i++) {
document.getElementById("utskrift").innerHTML+= i + " Years in the future your money is worth " + money + " Kr today." + "<br/>"
money *= 0.97;
  }  
}
```

Each year the remainder of the money decreases by 3% it’s exact ?

Comment: Yes! this is what i meant, thank you so much. can you explain what i did wrong in my code?

Comment: @SuzdarIbrahim that's what I wrote in a [previous edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47583351/4) and you said it's **not** what you want...

Comment: My pleasure, you ´ve created a loop which subtract 15 on the remainder (loop 15 times and the — substract 1) instead of multiply the remainder by 0.97 each times of the loop ;)

Comment: Yes you right i did’t see your previous comment but it’s the idea